# What is the difference between these two Technic half bushings?

Tags: piece-information, technic

While randomly browsing some LEGO sites, I came across a weird (to me anyway) looking bushing. Its part [4265c](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4265c). Below is one of the images describing it and the left one I recognize, but the right one I have never seen. It looks like there is some built-in play to the axis.

So my questions:

1. Are the two bushings on the image interchangeable?
2. Are they both really referred to by the same id ([4265c](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4265c))?
3. Is there any practical difference between the two?
4. Are there any specific use cases where the second would be preferred over the first one?

[image: Bushing 4265c]

Comment: Related to: [What's the difference between these hole shapes?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/4277/56)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both appear to have the same part ID despite being quite different.

Sariel answers most of your questions in *The Unofficial LEGO Technic Builder's Guide*.

> **toothed half bush with a cutout**
>
> The second variant, the toothed half bush with a cutout, is exactly
>   what its name implies: a copy of the previous version with part of the
>   axle hole cut out, which makes the axle hole large (see Figure 4-13).
>
> This modification was introduced to make it easier for children to
>   take half bushes on and off the axles, and that's exactly what makes
>   it much less popular with builders: These bushes are more likely to
>   shift when stressed than the first variant.
>
> Other than that, it has every quality of the original toothed half
>   bush except that, having been introduced a few years later, it's newer
>   and thus made of strong material.
>
> (Chapter 4. Page 36.)

Pawel "Sariel" Kmiec, 2012. *The Unofficial LEGO Technic Builder's Guide*. 1 Edition. No Starch Press.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... [brickowl](http://www.brickowl.com) lists the right picture for [4265c](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-half-bushing-32123) while [peeron](http://www.peeron.com) lists [the left picture](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4265c?img=20791).

This leads me to think that both are interchangeable and that the one in the right picture is a more cost-efficient version of 4265c (using slightly less ABS). [Lego Pick-a-Brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) also shows the version in the picture on the right.